# in-built C++ function that makes case insensitive comparision of two strings

Tags: c++, string

Is there any in-built function in C++ library that is able to make case insensitive comparision of two strings ? I am aware of simple approaches like using toupper/tolower,writing function ourselves.I want to know if there is anything in string.h library or other which is able to meet above objective.Here, 
strcasecmp of C don't support strings,so not much of help in C++.It only works with char *.
Any help would be very thankful.

P.S. Boost libraries won't be of much help.

Thanks.

Comment: In boost it would be a one liner: `boost::iequals(str1, str2);`. Too bad they won't be of much help.

Comment: You can create your own string variation that allows case insensitive comparison. [This link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_067.html) explains how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to call `strcasecmp`, then you can call it in C++ too:

```
int cmp_result = strcasecmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());
```

Comment: it's quite helpful to me.Thanks

Comment: sory that was my mistake.Your answer is pretty good.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. C++ does not provide any meaningful textual support beyond simply storing it. You will have to look to ICU.